# Defining settings in a Django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, settings

I'm making a simple blog application on Django, using PyCharm as IDE.

If I try to use Python Console, I get this error every time.

```
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

If I open console command line in Terminal, I have to specify my settings using this command every time:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

It looks like manage.py file already has a settings reference but for some reason it seems to be ignored:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Example.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PyCharm virtual environment. You have a option `Edit Configurations`, By click this a popup window is open. Then find `Environment variable`, and set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Example.settings`

[image: Edit conf]

Comment: Can't find this Edit configuration option. Can you provide the exact manu path?

Comment: I attached an image. Here, my use name `mess_balance` your name anything. By click on it you find the option

Comment: Do I have to do anything extra? I still get an error. Here's what I have in environment variables: ```PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Example.settings```

Comment: Yes it is. And also check `wsgi.py` is it `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Example.settings')`

Comment: Yes, it's that.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify. I am working on email notifications and have added this line so I can see how it works in terminal: ```EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'```. It's the last line of settings.py. And the full error text is ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```.